# Display the amount of the order on the block cart

Tags: commerce

do you know how to display the amount of the basket next to the number of elements?
As this page http://demo.commerceguys.com/cart

thank you

```
/**
* Returns the title of the shopping cart menu item with an item count.
*/
function commerce_cart_menu_item_title() {
global $user;

// Default to a static title.
$title = t('Shopping cart');

// If the user actually has a cart order...
if ($order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid)) {
// Count the number of product line items on the order.
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$quantity = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items,             commerce_product_line_item_types());

// If there are more than 0 product line items on the order...
if ($quantity > 0) {
  // Use the dynamic menu item title.
  $title = format_plural($quantity, 'Shopping cart (1 item)', 'Shopping   cart (@count items)');
 }
 }

return $title;
 }
```

Comment: I notice you posted this same question in multiple forums. Please only post such questions to Drupal Answers in the future, as it increases the maintenance burden on us as support givers to link these all together after you've posted them.

Answer (score 2):

In Commerce Kickstart, you're actually looking at a [view](https://github.com/commerceguys/kickstart-drops-7/blob/master/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/commerce_kickstart/commerce_kickstart_product_ui/includes/commerce_kickstart_product_ui.views_default.inc). The footer of the view displays a line item summary:

[image: Line item view modal dialog box]

You can read through the [handler's render() function](https://github.com/commerceguys/kickstart-drops-7/blob/master/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/line_item/includes/views/handlers/commerce_line_item_handler_area_line_item_summary.inc#L80-L132) to see how it actually gets that information.